# Grails dirtyPropertyNames returning empty textarea that was previously empty

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have a domain class with a few fields. One is a String called comments who's constraints are:

comments nullable: true, maxSize:512

Comments is a text area on a GSP. In the controller method to update, a call to domain.dirtyPropertyNames returns the comments field even if it is empty and was previously empty. This only seems to happen the first time I try to update. On all other updates domain.dirtyPropertyNames does not return the comments field if it was empty before and is still empty.

Is there some reason that an empty text area field bound to a String in the domain, would be registered in the first update of a domain object as dirty if it is empty and was previously empty? The value has not changed.

Comment: What version of Grails are you using? Also, is the value being saved as blank?

Comment: Grails 2.4.3. After further debugging the value is initially null and the form submission does submit an empty string. This it is updated in the database from null to "". However I thought by default Grails turned empty strings to null. Maybe this doesn't work on text areas?

Comment: That's correct, in 2.3.x that change was made. Verify your `Config.groovy` doesn't have `grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull = false` in it. Also, if you can post your domain with any mappings that might help get to the root of the issue. Also, how are you doing your data binding? Default or anything custom? Maybe even post your controller code.